# Watch only css changes with grunt

Tags: css, gruntjs

I have a basic project setup with index.html and styles.css in the root folder. I want my changes to the .css file to cause automatic refresh in the browser everytime I click save. This is the content of my gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    watch: {
      styles: {
              files: ['styles.css'],
              options: {
                  livereload: true
              }
          },
      },
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

  // Default task(s).
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);

};
```

But, when I run `grunt watch` in `cmd`, I get:

`>> File "styles.css" changed.
Warning: Task "css" not found. Use --force to continue.
Aborted due to warnings.`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am unsure as to why "styles: {" is in there? Have you tried without that nesting?

Comment: Excellent, now there are no errors! But I still don't get a live browser refresh when I click save on the css file. Any help?

Comment: Can you update your code above please, and maybe the answer will occur to me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically your livereload declaration is nested wrong, and as discussed above the "styles" is erroneous, I think this should work for you:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    watch: {
      livereload:  {
        options: {
        livereload: true
      },
      files: [
        'styles.css'
      ]
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

  // Default task(s).
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);

};
```

Comment: Yeah, I also added the livereload script `<script src="//localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>` in my html file. Still no live refresh.. Any help?

Comment: Try the livereload extension available for Chrome, you will not need the script, or at least I don't.

Comment: Have you cracked it?

Comment: No.. I installed the extension and also added port and hostname under the livereload property. Still no luck... The error I get is `Required config property 'watch.livereload.files' missing`.

Comment: Maybe styles.css is wrong? Try *.css or of course the path is maybe css/styles.css

Comment: Oh hang on. Put the files section UNDER livereload, editing my answer...